# Avoid multiple array traversals in JavaScript

Tags: javascript

The goal of the code is to produce a new array that combines all the labels with a numeric component of 10 or greater into a single object with a label of `V10+`. The new objects value will be the value of the greatest label.

In the following example, `V13` was the greatest label therefore its value will be used:

`[{'V10', 11}, {'V11', 123}, {'V12', 112}, {'V13', 120}] => {'V10+', 120}`

Currently I have to use `find`, `map` then `reduce` on the array. Does anyone have a suggestion to simplify this?

```js
var someObjects = [
    {'label': 'VS', 'value': 1 },
    {'label': 'V1', 'value': 2 },
    {'label': 'V2', 'value': 3 },
    {'label': 'V3', 'value': 4 },
    {'label': 'V4', 'value': 5 },
    {'label': 'V5', 'value': 6 },
    {'label': 'V6', 'value': 7 },
    {'label': 'V7', 'value': 8 },
    {'label': 'V8', 'value': 9 },
    {'label': 'V9', 'value': 10 },
    {'label': 'V10', 'value': 11 },
    {'label': 'V11', 'value': 123 },
    {'label': 'V12', 'value': 112 },
    {'label': 'V13', 'value': 120 },
    {'label': 'VE', 'value': 13 }
];

var maxObjVal = someObjects.find(function(obj) {
    var max =  Math.max.apply(null, someObjects.map(function (s) {
        var labelNumber = s.label.substring(1);
        return +labelNumber || 0;
    }));

    return obj.label == 'V' + max;
}).value;

var result = someObjects.reduce(function (ten) {
        return function (r, a) {
            var n = +a.label.substring(1);
            if (n >= 10) {
                if (!ten) {
                    ten = { label: 'V10+', value: maxObjVal };
                    r.push(ten);
                }
            } else {
                r.push(a);
            }
            return r;
        };
    }(), []);

console.log('result: ' + JSON.stringify(result));
```

Comment: please post your code here

Comment: You might try explaining the goal of the code as well.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You might be able to get away with a single iteration through the array. Try this after your definition of someObjects:

```
var resultArray = [];
var tenObj = null;
var maxVal;

someObjects.forEach(function (s) {
    // Get the number from the label (if possible)
    var labelNumber = s.label.substring(1);
    labelNumber = +labelNumber || 0;

    // Update the maxVal
    maxVal = maxVal ? Math.max(maxVal, s.value) : s.value;

    // Check for a label number >= 10
    if (labelNumber >= 10) {
        if (!tenObj) {
            tenObj = { label: 'V10+', value: 0}; // We'll set this value later
            resultArray.push(tenObj);
        }
    } else {
        resultArray.push(s);
    }
}));

// Update the value of the tenObj
if (tenObj) {
    tenObj.value = maxVal;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

It is possible to accomplish this in a single iteration if your willing to sacrifice your higher-order functions. Just keep track of the max values and create the new array on the fly. Afterwards you can push the `V10+` with the max value to the array.

```js
    var someObjects = [
    {'label': 'VS', 'value': 1 },
    {'label': 'V1', 'value': 2 },
    {'label': 'V2', 'value': 3 },
    {'label': 'V3', 'value': 4 },
    {'label': 'V4', 'value': 5 },
    {'label': 'V5', 'value': 6 },
    {'label': 'V6', 'value': 7 },
    {'label': 'V7', 'value': 8 },
    {'label': 'V8', 'value': 9 },
    {'label': 'V9', 'value': 10 },
    {'label': 'V10', 'value': 11 },
    {'label': 'V11', 'value': 123 },
    {'label': 'V12', 'value': 112 },
    {'label': 'V13', 'value': 120 },
    {'label': 'VE', 'value': 13 }
];

result = [];
// Will keep track of max label and value. e.g. [13, 120]
maxValue = [0, 0];

let getNumbers = (s) => { return +s.substring(1) || 0 };

someObjects.forEach(function(element) {
    if (element.hasOwnProperty("label")) {
        let number = getNumbers(element["label"]);
        if (number < 10) { // Keep this object as is
            result.push(element)
        } else {
            if (number > maxValue[1]) { // Check for a new max
                maxValue[0] = element["value"];
                maxValue[1] = number
            }
        }
    }
});
// Finally push the aggregated label and max value to the array.
result.push({"label": 'V10+', 'value': maxValue[0]});
console.log(result);
```

Comment: This assumes that there are entries that exceed 10. What if the someObjects array does not have any V10 or V11, etc? This will add an entry into result regardless.